# SQL level paging without total rows

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, .net-3.5, ado.net

Is it possible to convert the following script so that it can be called directly from ADO .NET? I don't want it to be a stored procedure, and I don't need `TotRows` if that makes it easier to convert.

```
DECLARE @startRow INT ; SET @startrow = 50
;WITH cols
AS
(
    SELECT table_name, column_name, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name, column_name) AS seq, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name DESC, column_name desc) AS totrows
    FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].columns
)
SELECT table_name, column_name, totrows + seq -1 as TotRows
FROM cols
WHERE seq BETWEEN @startRow AND @startRow + 49
ORDER BY seq
```

Comment: Why do you think that needs to be a stored proc? What is your client written in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you'd need to do to use inline SQL from C# is to use a parameter instead of a local variable.

Like so.

```
using(SqlConnection cnn = GetAConnection())
{
    string sql = @"WITH cols
        AS
        (
        SELECT table_name, column_name, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name, column_name) AS seq, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name DESC, column_name desc) AS totrows
        FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].columns
        )
        SELECT table_name, column_name, totrows + seq -1 as TotRows
        FROM cols
        WHERE seq BETWEEN @startRow AND @startRow + 49
        ORDER BY seq";

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,cnn);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startRow",50);

   cnn.Open();
   using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {

         //Do something with the reader here.
   }

}
```